# Prove the following theorem in propositional calculus

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the following Hilbert-style propositional calculus, having the logical connectives $\{\neg,\rightarrow\}$ of arity one and two respectively, and the following axioms:

A1: $A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow A)$

A2: $(A\rightarrow(B\rightarrow C))\rightarrow((A\rightarrow B)\rightarrow(A\rightarrow C))$

A3: $(\neg A\rightarrow \neg B)\rightarrow (B\rightarrow A).$

$A,B,C$ are any well-formed formulas (wffs). The only inference rule is modus ponens. I want to prove the following theorem:

$\vdash (\neg A\rightarrow A)\rightarrow A$ for any wff $A$.

You may use any or all of the following theorems without proof:

$\vdash A\rightarrow A$ for any wff $A$.

$A\rightarrow B, B\rightarrow C\vdash A\rightarrow C$ for any wffs $A,B,C$.

$A\rightarrow (B\rightarrow C), B\vdash A\rightarrow C$ for any wffs $A,B,C$.

$\vdash \neg A\rightarrow (A\rightarrow B)$ for any wffs $A,B$.

Please avoid using the deduction theorem unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: "Avoid using the deduction theorem" for a Hilbert-style calculus is a recipe for absolute misery. Why would you want that?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Frege, Lukasiewicz, Russell, Hilbert, and others, as well plenty of theorem-provers avoid using the deduction theorem.

Answer (score 2):

*Lemma*

1) $\vdash \lnot A \to (A \to B)$ --- Th.4

2) $\vdash (\lnot A \to (A \to B)) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to \lnot B))$ --- Ax.2

3) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to \lnot B)$ --- from 1) and 2)

4) $\vdash (\lnot A \to \lnot B) \to (B \to A)$ --- Ax.3

> 5) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (B \to A)$ --- from 3) and 4) by Th.2

*Proof*

1) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A)$ --- from *Lemma*

2) $\vdash ((\lnot A \to A) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A)) \to (((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A)) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A))$ --- Ax.2

3) $\vdash ((\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A)) \to ((\lnot A \to A) \to A)$ --- from 1) and 2)

4) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to (\lnot A \to A)$ --- from Th.1

> 5) $\vdash (\lnot A \to A) \to A$ --- from 3) and 4)

Answer (score -1):

I use Polish notation.  Thus, instead I'll translate every wff of the form $\lnot$$\alpha$ into the form N$\alpha$.  Also, I'll translate every wff of the form ($\alpha$$\rightarrow$$\beta$) into the form C$\alpha$$\beta$.  Thus, the axioms can get translated to

A1 CxCyx

A2 CCxCyzCCxyCxz

A3 CCNxNyCxy

I'll also use spacing to help to indicate where a substitution of an axiom or previously proved theorem took place.

> 1 CxCyx
>
> 2 CCxCyzCCxyCxz
>
> 3 CCNxNyCyx
>
> 4 C CxCyx C z CxCyx from 1
>
> 5 CzCxCyx from {4, 1}
>
> 6 CC CxCyz C Cxy Cxz CC CxCyz Cxy C CxCyz Cxz from 2
>
> 7 CCCxCyzCxyCCxCyzCxz from {6, 2}
>
> 8 C CCNxNyCyx C z CCNxNyCyx from 1
>
> 9 CzCCNxNyCyx from {8, 3}
>
> 10 C CxCCyxz C x C y x from 5
>
> 11 CCC x C Cyx z C x Cyx CC x C Cyx z C x z from 7
>
> 12 CCxCCyxzCxz from {11, 10}
>
> 13 CC z C CNxNy Cyx CC z CNxNy C z Cyx from 2
>
> 14 CCzCNxNyCzCyx from {13, 9}
>
> 15 CC Nz CC Ny Nz Czy C Nz Czy from 12
>
> 16 C Nz CC Ny Nz C z y from 9
>
> 17 CNzCzy from {15, 16}
>
> 18 CC Nz C z y CC Nz z C Nz y from 2
>
> 19 CCNzzCNzy from {18, 17}
>
> 20 CC CNzz CN z N y C CNzz C y z from 14
>
> 21 CCN z z CN z Ny from 19
>
> 22 CCNzzCyz from {20, 21}
>
> 23 CC CNxx CC y CNxx x C CNxx x from 12
>
> 24 CCN x x C CyCNxx x from 22
>
> 25 CCNxxx from {23, 24}